# Get only string value of a field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to get all documents with a string for the field 'readings'. So in this example:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "readings": "string"
},
{
   "_id": 2,
   "readings": [
      "string"
   ]
}
```

... I need to get document **1** as a result, NOT document 2.

I tried this

```
db.collection.find( { "readings" : { $type: "string" } } )
```

but this will give me document 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this now:

```
db.collection.find( { "readings" : { $type : "string" }, "readings.0": { "$exists": false } } );
```

Reference: [MongoDB Match an array with $type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512764/mongodb-match-an-array-with-type)

Comment: Did a mistake in my post. I tried 'string', but this gives me document 2, which I need to be excluded.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks. I required only $type: "string";