# Delete documents where value is not an array

Tags: mongodb

It seems that mongodb allows the same syntax for deleting documents where the value is a single value, and whenever the value is present in a collection:

This

`db.SomeCollection.deleteMany({UserId: 12345});`

Can affect both `{UserId: 12345}` and `{UserId: [12345, 67895, 87897]}`.

I understand that this schema isn't ideal; we are using a singular `UserId` prop to denote both a single id int, and an array of ints. However, I've inherited a database that makes use of mongodb's dynamic nature, if you catch my drift.

What is the safest way to execute a `deleteMany` query, specifying I only want to delete documents where the value is a single integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator to check field type but it's not so obvious in this case. You can't check if `UserId` is of type `double` because MongoDB will indicate that array of doubles is a double as well (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512764/mongodb-match-an-array-with-type)). So you need to invert your logic and check if documents you're trying to remove are not an array (type `4`):

```
db.SomeCollection.deleteMany({ $and: [ { UserId: 12345 }, { UserId: { $not: { $type: 4 } } } ] })
```